# jQuery UI - load tabs content on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI tabs and I want to load tab content only when it's clicked. I am trying to prevent loading content of non active tabs to reduce page load time.

I tried many things but I cant make this work.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JakubSkowronski/gn7k719u/6/)

```
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
  var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

  $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(1800).siblings().hide();

  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thank you

Comment: _I am trying to prevent loading content of non active tabs to reduce page load time._ where you're trying that?

Comment: Try [Jquery Ajax api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)